# How can I edit Office documents on an Android tablet and keep compatibility?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, pdf, asus-eee-pad-transformer

In our office, there's a new Eee Pad Transformer. It was supposed to replace a netbook for giving presentations and editing Microsoft Office documents on the go (e.g. Word, PowerPoint, Excel).

There have been some issues:

- The office solutions they currently tried can only *read* Microsoft Office files (like [Documents To Go](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogo&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kYXRhdml6LmRvY3N0b2dvIl0.))
- Polaris Office with *write* support produce Microsoft Office files that fail to open in Office 2007 <sub>Claim by the owner of the device, I can't try it.</sub>

The questions are:

- Is there any way to **produce PDF files from such documents**? This would at least make it possible to just export presentations to PDF in order to share them.
- Is there a (preferably free) office solution that **guarantees compatibility** with Office 2007/2010?
- Any other workarounds?

Comment: Don't ask how to accomplish your self made-up workaround, ask how to solve the problem instead. This will most likely result in better answers.

Comment: @Flow I know what you mean, and generally I also advise others to do so, but I can't currently tackle the writing/compatibility thing, and there *is* a need for PDF writing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have [MobiSystems OfficeSuite 5](http://www.mobisystems.com/android_office/) for my Android (phone, not tablet though).  But I have never had any problems editing files, saving them and then opening them in Office 2007 & 2010.  It does not have a save as PDF, but it does let you save in either .doc or .docx formats for word, xls & xlsx for Excel, and .ppt & pptx for Powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered uploading the documents to Google Docs and using the [Android Google docs app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5hcHBzLmRvY3MiXQ..) in the tablet?

We use this system to allow mobile devices to access shared documents and work pretty well. I you combine this with [Google Cloud connect](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudconnect?hl=en) you can edit the documents directly from Office when you are at the office or from Google Docs when you are away.

Answer (score -1):

If there's nothing better, Adobe has a free-to-use (except your doc't goes to their site: slight privacy risk) conversion web app; see their main site..